# Reducing the size of a black-and-white scanned pdf

Tags: preview, scanning, image-processing

I have a 352 page pdf that is a scan of a black-and-white text. The file size is 60.9 MB, which seems excessively large too me. (Is it indeed?)

Is there an easy way to convert this file to a more compressed one?

---

Edit. Here's a little sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60MB is probably OK for a greyscale scan of 350 pages.  I have some 100pg color scans that clock around 30MB.  If you meant it's actually black and white (and no grey) then it's definitely too big.

Preview is probably a bad tool to try to get the file size down without hurting image quality.  The only tools available will resample the image to a lower resolution.  What I use in a case like this is Acrobat Pro, which will let me convert the compression of the embedded scans to JPEG2000, which can save a lot of space over normal JPEG and retain quality.

Comment: Given the limited use I intend to make of it, I find USD 299 a bit steep. :) But thanks for the other information.

Comment: There's a 30-day trial of Adobe apps, with Acrobat at http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=acrobat_pro&loc=us&promoid=KHXXV .  If you have a short-term need to shrink a few files, this would be a good route.

Comment: That is one _big_ application. So, I did Save As Other... > Reduced Size PDF > Adobe 10.0.0, (I assume this is what you meant with JPEG2000?) and... waiting... down to 15.9 MB and sharp as before! Great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A great PDF compressor is Ghostscript (`gs`), which is native in most Linux distributions and easily installable for Mac OS X and Windows.

[Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3751/daniel) summarizes [it best here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller/19047#19047), with the key quote being his preferred options:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
    -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```

Comment: This worked great. `brew install gs` did the trick and got a 3MB pdf down to 940K. Still looks great.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just text and no images, it is indeed quite large.

There are several ways to compress the PDF file, and one of them is a simple solution with **Preview.app**:

- Open the file in **Preview.app**
- Go to the **File > Export...** menu option
- Provide a name for the file
- Below in the **Quartz Filter:** dropdown, choose **Reduce File Size** (the default would be "None")
- Click **Save**

If the result is a well compressed file but the readability is negatively impacted, you can try scanning at a much higher DPI and compressing it (to get a better compromise between file size and readability) or use a third party product to do OCR on the file (PDFPen, PDFScanner, VueScan and ABBYY FineReader are just some of the several options available).

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion and indeed it went from 60.9 to 23.1 MB. However, the text became fuzzy, virtually unreadable. :(

Comment: That's one of the gambles with any image compression. You would have to scan it at a higher DPI and then compress it to get a better compromise between file size and legibility.

Comment: [VueScan](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/4763/vuescan) has a free demo. Not quite sure how to go about going from pdf to pdf. (Rescanning the paper is a psychological no-no.)

Answer (score 0):

Found this online tool, it compressed my 100 MB b&w pdf to 18 MB using the medium setting, quality is still very acceptable for reading.

https://www.ilovepdf.com/compress_pdf

It may be a problem if the user has restricted bandwidth as the file has to uploaded and re-downloaded, Dropbox or Google Drive integration is also offered as an alternative but I have not tested it.